# Same rosdep key for a system dependency and a ROS package

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will it create conflicts if I try to release a ROS package which has the same name as a rosdep key for an existing Debian package? So, basically, if I'm not mistaken it will be a new entry in the distribution file:

https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/indigo/distribution.yaml

with the same name as an existing entry in the rosdep keys list:

https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml

So, assuming that it is possible, what will happen when somebody will depend on that package in their package.xml: will rosdep get confused or will it choose one of the two alternatives and if so which one will it be (the ROS package or the Debian package or the behaviour is non-deterministic)?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189824/same-rosdep-key-for-a-system-dependency-and-a-ros-package/) by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, they will collide. ROS Packages and rosdep keys are used in the same namespace. If you're creating a package which wraps the functionality of a debian package your name should reflect the different scope.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2